# Yes or no (-y or -n) for Clone multiply-claimed blocks while using e2fsck -f

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, fsck

I am trying to shrink EBS Volume from 2TB to 1TB as we are utilizing only 30% of the volume. I have created a new 1TB volume(already partitioned) and attached old 2TB and new 1TB volume as secondary (xvdf1 and xvdg1). The process includes e2fsck -f /dev/xvdf1 (check), resize2fs -M -p /dev/xvdf1(resize) and dd bs=16M if=/dev/xvdf1 of=/dev/xvdg1 count=value from resize step (copy)

While disk check e2fsck -f /dev/xvdf1, I am getting Clone multiply-claimed blocks? and asking for a yes/no answer. Now, I know - can use -y or -n parameter with e2fsck. All my code, mongo database and Postgres database are in the same volume.

What is recommended here so that I should not lose any data and have a lesser downtime as we have a standalone deployment?

Comment: Have you read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506040/108618)?

Comment: Yes, but still I am not able to understand what should I do in my case.
We have a single EBS volume (2TB, 830GB Used) mounted as root (sda1) which contains everything, code, postgresDB and MongoDB. I am trying to copy the data using dd to a new 1TB volume.
I tried the steps for volume shrinking as mentioned in the below link
https://matt.berther.io/2015/02/03/how-to-resize-aws-ec2-ebs-volumes/
with -y(yes) tag for clone-multiply-claimed-blocks and everything was done properly. But when I used the 1 TB volume as root, I found that there is something very wrong with my mongo database.